# Magento 2 : Moving the Magento media directory to S3

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.0.7, amazon

Is there any way to load images directly from external url[amazon s3], instead of importing images in to the server? How to add external url to csv files while importing configurable products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3.
S3 Extension for Magento 2, helps to upload images straight to s3.

Comment: Showing 404 :(
does it need access from owner?

Comment: @SatishGadhave: https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3

Comment: one paid extension found https://magecomp.com/magento-2-amazon-s3.html

Comment: @GauravJain it’s misleading to write "found" when you are working at the company who sell this module.